# Как синхронизировать сайт интернет-магазина и приложения?

Tags: веб-программирование, api

Хочу сделать сайт интернет-магазина с приложением, но не очень понимаю как их синхронизировать. Я же правильно понимаю, что у них должна быть одна бд?

Получается можно будет написать сайт на условном django, а приложение на flutter, да?

Comment: У них должен быть общий бэк-энд - это не только бд, но и весь функционал магазина. Сайт и приложение, они же фронт-энды или клиенты - стучатся к нему через REST API. Их задача исключительно во взаимодействии с юзером.

Answer (score 0):

Самое верное решение - сделать правильную архитектуру. У вас будет сервер, который по запросам будет предоставлять информацию пользовательскому интерфейсу(а какой он уже не важно). Так ваша веб-страница будет обращаться к серверу запросами (например: *получить список актуальных товаров* или *оформить заказ*)и получать необходимые данные и мобильное приложение так же. А сама база будет сотрудничать уже только с сервером. Причём такая архитектура, вроде, не зависит от инструментов.

Comment: То есть я могу создать сайт на nodejs, подключить rest api и через него обращаться условно к mongodb , а потом сделать приложение на flutter и через rest api с теми же командами обращаться к этой же бд(mongodb )?

Comment: @penelopafonkeks да, но будет лучше если nodejs будет общаться с flatter а flatter с mongodb